How do I change root password on MySQL?
I have checked more than 25 answers in AskUbuntu; none of them apply... I seem to be an edge case in this instance.
I know that an empty password was assigned because there is an entry in the MySQL log confirming this.  Despite this clue (in the log files), I cannot log in with mysql -u root -p.  The enter key response to the request for password is refused as being invalid.
As I said, it seems to be an edge case, since all the attempted solutions (that I've tried) presume that, in the case of empty password, you can log in and change it.
Despite the log reporting that an empty password was assigned, I cannot log in with an "empty password" (i.e. pressing  for password).
ENVIRONMENT
Ubuntu Studio 23.10
MySQL 8.0.36
MYSQL LOG
2024-04-19T07:15:40.204390Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.23.10.1).
...
2024-04-16T18:27:18.733173Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
...


Unless I'm mistaken sudo mysql -u root will straight log you in as root?

That could work if I had a password.  Because the response to "sudo mysql -u root" requires a password; and it won't accept enter meaning no password.

Yeah sorry, I actually meant: sudo mysql. I'm pretty sure there was a way...

I completely removed and re-installed the server.  And, yes, "sudo mysql -u root -p" works as expected.

So is this fixed? Otherwise you can look into logging in to MySQL as debian-sys-maint and change the password using that account, that should work (unless you can't login as debian-sys-maint either of course...)

Yes.  A complete reinstall worked for me... earlier I was trying to minimize the download... resulting in partial removal (I use Synaptic).

Ok I tested this cause i was pretty sure at least one of those two commands should've worked; I explicitly set an empty password on a fresh server installation (ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by '';), and then I tried logging in using sudo mysql / sudo mysql -u root; they both worked. I believe you indeed had somehow set a password, simply not an empty one, which explains the error messages when running sudo mysql / sudo mysql -u root
